# How can I round all numbers in a file?

Tags: awk, math

How can I round all numbers in a file that countains several columns of numbers up to a certain precision? Can this be done with awk?

A single line looks like this:

```
text - 0.1655456615 - 0.158645 - 0.846554 - 0.85251 ##
```

EDIT: '-' is a column delimiter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's more easily done with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/[-+]?\d*(?:\.?\d|\d\.)\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?/sprintf("%.2g",$&)/ge'
```

Comment: That seems to generate numbers with a different precision, e.g., 0.03747117319160571667 is rounded to 0.03747?

Comment: That gives `0.037` for me which is a precision of 2. Maybe you want `.2f` instead of `.2g` for 2 digits after the decimal point (0.04) or `.2e` (3.75e-02)

Comment: 2f was what I needed. That solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you only have awk available:

```
awk '{
    while (match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)) {
        printf "%s%.2f", substr($0, 1, RSTART-1), substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}'
```